# how to fix titlebar behaving as transparent when using '-transparentcolor' in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

python 3.10, 3.11, windows 10

short:

transparency is affecting title bar when it shouldn't, simple code with example below, move the window to the middle of the screen, maximise and restore to reproduce the behaviour

long:

I know it looks so simple, but please bear with me. This thing is driving me nuts. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, it looks like a bug, maybe?

Maximising (or restoring to normal state after maximise) breaks the title bar. Title bar is not registering mouse clicks, I can't close the window or resize it because click goes through. It acts as it if it was transparent. In the main app I am using another hidden window with -alpha to grab mouse events on transparent canvas. Both windows are bound together and act as one. Having second window behind this one also doesn't help. Both windows are affected and unclickable (well, -alpha part of the window is clickable, but not the title bar).

I made a very short code to reproduce this behaviour. You can try it with frame instead of a canvas, or a button. Result is the same. Curious thing I have also discovered when using #000000 for colour - it breaks the window in even weirder way. Not sure what to make of it. #000001 works the same as yellow (or blue, red, etc.).

example:

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk

root = Tk()
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'yellow', '-topmost', True)
root.geometry("600x600")

x = Canvas(root, bg='yellow')
x.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

If I try different width and height values, sometimes I can grab only half of the title bar or close the window, but not minimise. It seems to depend on where the window is on the screen and the size of the object. Feels like the transparent part of the object is extending through the title bar making it unresponsive. I tried separating the title bar from the rest of the window with frames or shapes but it doesn't help (sometimes it works, but is dependent on size and location of the window - you may get lucky and not notice the behaviour)

```
x = Canvas(root, bg='yellow', height=600, width=600)
x.pack()
```

The best solution I've come up with so far:

```
def refresh(self):
    self.state('iconic')
    if self.state() == 'iconic':
        self.state('normal')
        self.focus_force() # needed for Entry widget
```

This function assigned to the button which is minimising the window to the taskbar and then returning it to normal state immediately. Obviously this is far from elegant, because the user have to perform an unnecessary action. I could use overrideredirect and hopefully recreate resize and close functionality of the window but it seems like an overkill for rather simple app.

Not sure what else to say. It's late, bye

edit:

trying this now and it somehow works, but sometimes the window blinks uncomfortably.

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bind("<Map>", self.refresh)

        self.canv = Canvas(self)
        self.canv.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    def refresh(self, event):
        if self.state() == 'normal':
            self.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'yellow', '-topmost', True)
            self.canv.configure(bg='yellow')
        elif self.state() == 'zoomed':
            self.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'blue', '-topmost', True)
            self.canv.configure(bg='blue')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Window()
    w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Python 3.10 is depreciated. You should update 3.11 or later

Comment: unfortunately updating python didn't help.

Comment: I can't imagine it would. Both Python 3.10 and 3.11 ship with tkinter 8.6. Also, Python 3.10 isn't "deprecated" - support doesn't end until October of 2026.